# Java frequency in a list

Tags: java

The problem is with nullpointexception. When i enter for example: 1 1 1 4 - everything works perfectly fine, because the input is the same size as the array size. But if i enter 1 1 4 - i get exception and can't figure out how to fix it. Maybe someone has any ideas about this?

Comment: Why don't you use a Map, it much easier.

Comment: Collections.max(arrList) returns the maximum element in the list. Not the length of the list. So using new Integer[maxSize] doesn't make sense. Your method needs the original list of integer as input, and it must create another list (or array) for its output. You can't use the same array for both.

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: @isnot2bad if (arr[elementIndex] > 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is some kind of assignment, so you should solve that without using high-level pre-built java algorithms. As you tried to solve the problem by yourself, I'm willing to help. Your main issue has nothing to do with the algorithm itself, but with some Java-specialties concerning boxing/unboxing: The array element you are trying to access is `null`, in which case, conversion to integer (unboxing) won't work and throws an `NullPointerException`.

Instead of solving the `NullPointerException` problem I suggest reviewing the assignment from beginning:

If we assume, that we already know the minimum and maximum value of the input numbers, it is easy to compute the frequencies of all input numbers:

```
/**
 * @param input the input numbers
 * @param min   the minimum input number (min(input))
 * @param max   the maximum input number (max(input))
 * @return      the frequency of all input numbers as array. The n-th array element denotes the frequence of the number n+min.
 */
int[] frequency(int[] input, int min, int max) {
    int[] result = new int[max - min + 1];  // e.g. int[4] for min = 2 and max = 5
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) { // iterate all input numbers
        int n = input[i];    // the number
        int index = n - min; // the index in the frequency array
        result[index]++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The minimum and maximum values can easily be computed as follows:

```
/**
 * Computes the boundaries (minimum and maximum) of the given number array
 * @param input the input numbers
 * @return      the minimum and maximum number of the input numbers as array of length 2. The first element is the minimum, the second element the maximum value.
 */
int[] boundaries(int[] input) {
    int[] result = new int[2]; // result[0] = min, result[1] = max
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        int n = input[i];
        min = Math.min(min, n);
        max = Math.max(max, n);
    }

    return new int[] { min, max };
}
```

The rest is simple:

```
/**
 * Computes the frequencies of the given input numbers.
 * @returns the frequencies of the input numbers as two-dimensional array. The first element of the array is an array of the frequencies, the second element the array of numbers. 
 */
int[][] frequencies(int[] input) {
    // get min/max of input
    int[] minMax = boundaries(input);
    int min = minMax[0];
    int max = minMax[1];

    // compute frequencies
    int[] frequencies = frequency(input, min, max);

    // create numbers array
    int[] numbers = new int[frequencies.length]);
    for(int i = 0; < frequency.length; ++i) {
       numbers[i] = min + i;
    }

    // assembly two dimensional result array
    return new int[][] { frequencies, numbers };
}
```

All this can be done simpler by using built-in mechanisms of the java runtime environment (e.g. the streaming-API to compute min/max values).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Map` to keep `number->frequency` data. You can group by data by using streams

```
Map<Integer, Long> counted = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: This does not include intermediate numbers that are not in the list, but adding those can easily be done in a second step.

Comment: I'll try using Map

Answer (score 0):

Integer maxSize = Collections.max(arrList);

returns you the maximum element in the collection.

use `Integer maxSize = arrList.size()`

instead of `Integer maxSize = Collections.max(arrList);`

Comment: Yes, it returns max element, and it makes sense. Because i need loop through all elements till the max element , not through input size.
You can see my explanation in example:

Example:

A = [1, 4, 1, 5, 8, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 7, 2]

Output:

frequency:5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1

number :1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Comment: With input 1 1 4 cause you to create array of size 4
Integer[] A = arrList.toArray(new Integer[maxSize]);
but since you have 3 elements, A would look like below
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 4
A[3] = null, which is causing you null pointer

Comment: @Ntel if you're supposed to loop till the max element, then the max element in your example is 8, so you should stop looping when you reach 8, and the frequency of 3 should thus be 0, since there is no 3 before 8 in the array. You should loop through **all** the elements, not until the max element, and you should compute their respective frequency, that you should then store in a separate array.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, instead of an array, you can make use of the **Collection** and perform **Collection.frequency(Collection, Object)** on it.

> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to
>   the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e
>   in the collection such that Objects.equals(o, e).

[Collections.frequency​(Collection c, Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object))